# How to clone /boot and LUKS-encrypted root partitions to a new disk with a different partition table

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

The system in question is installed on an 80GB HDD that's on its last legs. Partition table is msdos, and has a `/boot` partition, and encrypted `swap` and `/` partitions. The swap is no longer used so I'd prefer to ditch this as I go.

The disk I have to replace it is a 6TB WD Red, and due to its size I need to use gpt, so I can't just `dd` the entire disk. I'd like it to have the same size `/boot` partition and just have the remainder be an encrypted `/` partition.

I've had this system running well for quite some time and since then I've completely lost track of every last thing I did to get it the way it is, so hopefully I have an option available beyond "reinstall and start over". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a couple hours testing everything and it all works exactly the same as before, so I'm calling this solved, and since I just found out that not only can I answer my own question but [I'm encouraged to](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5664/does-answering-your-own-question-constitute-abuse-on-ask-ubuntu), here it is:

1. Boot to live USB and install Xubuntu onto the new drive from scratch, creating new partitions as desired but being sure to use the exact same username, pw, &c as the original.
2. Run `update`, `dist-upgrade`, `clean` and `autoremove` in `apt-get` on the new installation.
3. Reboot to old HDD, run same updates on old install
4. Reboot to live USB, run `lsblk` to check which is where, then:

   ```
   apt-get install cryptsetup
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[old root partition] [old partition's name]
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[new root partition] [new partition's name]
   mount /dev/mapper/[old partition's name] /mnt/oldroot
   mount /dev/mapper/[new partition's name] /mnt/root
   cp /mnt/root/etc/fstab [somewhere safe]
   cp -axfv /mnt/oldroot/* /mnt/root
   cp [somewhere safe]/fstab /mnt/root/etc/
   ```
5. shut down, disconnect the old drive and the live USB, and boot to the new drive

Unlike what other answers to similar questions suggest I found there's no need to mount either boot partition from the live USB, nor any need to bother with `mount -B`/`chroot`/`update-grub`, and no need to touch `fstab` except to back it up and restore it. Surprised it worked since this was a shot at the dark at 3am, but it did. Hopefully this helps someone else down the line!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a useful procedure to store. I have no idea if one can store useful answers/procedures one accidentally stumbles upon, but hey, answering it does store it in the my "questions" area. Sorry for the abuse, do no see any "mark" option anywhere..